# Unix sorting processes by date

Tags: bash, unix, scripting-language

hello guys I am having troubles sorting by date, I have to keep just the newest proccess and kill the older ones

```
 ps -ef | grep -i my_username
```

then I get let's say 5 or 6 process but I don't know which one is the newest one pls help.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is what you want to do. If there are more than 5 or 6 processes running under your name, your login shell  will not be among the newest processes. Generally speaking, killing it will kill all your processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming none of your processes is more than 24 hours old,

ps -ef | grep -i my_username | sort +4

will probably suffice

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this on Linux, this will sort the processes by start time:

```
ps -ef --sort=start_time
```

To get the top 5, you can pipe the output to `head`:

```
ps -ef --sort=start_time | head -n 6
```

I've specified 6 as the top row is a header.

For OS X, this will give you the top 5 oldest processes:

```
ps aux -O started | head -n 6
```

Comment: I get this   illegal option -- sort=start_time

Comment: What unix system is this - OS X? Also, just to be sure, there's no space after the `--`.

Comment: I wanted the last 10 ones ` ps -ef --sort=start_time | tail -n 10`

Answer (score 0):

If this is Linux, then you can get the start-time of your processes like this:

```
ps -u your_username -o pid,lstart,cmd
```

Though, since the `lstart` field is date-formatted, I'll admit it's a bit hard to sort on automatically. But if you only have "5 or 6 processes" to care about, then maybe you can just  do that manually. :)